# Is an element's "atomic electron configuration" EXACTLY equal to the term with the largest coefficient in the CI series of the neutral atom?

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

For atoms and molecules with more than one electron, the wavefunction cannot be written as a single Slater determinant, so the ground-state configuration of (the atom or molecule in question) is defined as the configuration whose Slater determinant has the largest (in absolute value) coefficient in the configuration interaction(CI) infinite series expansion.

My question is the following- let one set an element, say aluminium. Then, does the term with the largest coefficient in (the CI series converging to the EXACT wavefunction of a neutral atom of aluminium) EXACTLY consist of the 13 one-electron wavefunctions corresponding to 1s²2s²2p⁶3s²3p¹, without containing any 4s, 3d, 4p(etc) one-electron wavefunctions in the determinant?

Comment: I have a feeling: no.

Comment: After reading this again, I'm quite convinced that the first paragraph is incorrect to start with. For more than one electron you can write the wave function as a single Slater determinant, it simply won't be the exact wave function. CI is, even at is limit, technically just a way to express the ground state; the configuration with the largest coefficient doesn't really have any physical meaning. It only is the best single determinant approximation. From all that I have to revise my last comment. I have a feeling: yes.